# microtime mouse click speed

Tags: javascript, php

I am sure this has been cover  by many people. So sorry for asking What will work to control a  on click speed that someone can press.
  Need to not log the person out but need to slow the load on server as  user seam to   be using auto-clickers. i want to be-able to set in milliseconds.
  Exp 1)

```
<?php
// Checking Clicks
$now = microtime();
if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now-0.05)) { 
$message = 
die('<img src="images/Unknown.png" /> <img src="images/n.png"    /> <img > 
src="images/Unknown.png" /> <div class="Fail">Error: Don\'t </div>');
 }
 $_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

this works but will only do 1 sec microtime would not go  below  1 sec

so i was thing ing this would  be a workable  2)

```
 <?php
// Checking Clicks
$now = microtime(true);
if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now < 100)) { 
$message = 
die('<img src="images/Unknown.png" /> <img src="images/Unknown.png" /> <img 
src="images/unknown.png" /> <div class="Fail">Error: Don\'t </div>');
}
$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

or just a loop

```
<?php
// Checking Clicks
$now = for($i=0;$i<100;$i++);
if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now)) { 
$message = 
die('<img src="images/Unknown.png" /> <img src="images/Unknown.png" />  
<img 
src="images/Unknown.png" /> <div class="Fail">Error: Don\'t </div>');
}
$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

Thanks what  would be  best and what is wrong  no need  for time stamp in  db

Comment: If you are sure it has been asked, why don't you look for the answer? ;)
Where do you set your $now variable? It is rather hard to help with gaps in the code. (microtime(true) will give you microseconds if that helps)

Comment: `($now < 100)` is **ALWAYS** going to be false, since 100 occurred back in 1970, and is rather unlikely to ever occur again...

Comment: Sorry about the gap's  but  yes i would like the microseconds    so that it controls how many mouse clicks someone can do in  one second.  And yes  i did look   for  it before posting i just could not  find a stable  way. thanks MarcB you  made me laugh some with  1970